# csv file gets taken by app but doesn't get returned

Tags: java, xml, csv, mule

I have an internship with now training. I have the following code that i have in mule studio, this is only the java end. I think this is where the problem is.

Like is said, the csv file gets taken from the folder it is in, but it doesn't reach the output folder. any advice or tips welcome (if been working on it for almost 15 hours.)

```
package com.csvToXml.common;

import net.sf.flatpack.DefaultDataSet;
import net.sf.flatpack.DefaultParserFactory;
import net.sf.flatpack.Parser;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.StringReader;
import java.io.StringWriter;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException;
import javax.xml.transform.Transformer;
import javax.xml.transform.TransformerConfigurationException;
import javax.xml.transform.TransformerException;
import javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory;
import javax.xml.transform.dom.DOMSource;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamResult;
import java.io.BufferedReader;

import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.Element;




public class CsvConverter {


  public static int numberOfRows;
    public static int rowNumber = 0;
    public static int columnNumber = 0;


 private static char delimiter = ',';
 private static char qualifier = '"';
 private static boolean ignoreFirstRecord = true;

 public CsvConverter() {

 }

 public String convert(String csv)  {
  StringReader sr = new StringReader(csv);
  FileReader fr = null;

  //Get the configuration file for csv processing
  try {
   fr = new       FileReader("/users/jacqueslecoq/MuleStudio/workspace/stock/flows/usermap.xml");
  } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {   
   e.printStackTrace();
  }

  //The csv parser
  Parser p = DefaultParserFactory.getInstance().newDelimitedParser(fr, sr,delimiter,   qualifier, ignoreFirstRecord);

  DefaultDataSet d = (DefaultDataSet) p.parse();

  //Build the xml
  DocumentBuilderFactory dFact = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder build;
        Document doc=null;
  try {
   build = dFact.newDocumentBuilder();

        doc = build.newDocument();
  } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {

   e.printStackTrace();
  }
        Element root = doc.createElement("root");
         doc.appendChild(root);

        Element Details = doc.createElement("rows");
        root.appendChild(Details);


  while (d.next()) {

    String[] colums = d.getColumns();
    for(int i=0; i<colums.length;i++ ){
     Element name = doc.createElement(colums[i]);
              name.appendChild(doc.createTextNode(d.getString(colums[i])));
              Details.appendChild(name);
    }

  }
  TransformerFactory tf = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
  Transformer transformer=null;
  StringWriter writer = null;

  try {
   transformer = tf.newTransformer();
   writer = new StringWriter();
   transformer.transform(new DOMSource(doc), new StreamResult(writer));
  } catch (TransformerConfigurationException e) {

   e.printStackTrace();
  } catch (TransformerException e) {

   e.printStackTrace();
  }


  String output = writer.getBuffer().toString();

  return output;

 }
```

Comment: Is there any  Exception ?

Comment: provide us sample csv how it look like and data in it.

Comment: where is your configuration?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you don't provide enough information to help you, I'm going to give you random general advices instead :)

Since you're in Mule, there are things that you should let Mule do instead of coding it yourself. For example all the end of the method doing the DOM to XML transformation should be removed and replaced with an `<mulexml:dom-to-xml-transformer />` added right after your component.

Also, I imagine `usermap.xml` since it's in your project. If that's the case, why loading it each time? You could pre-load it once in `CsvConverter()`. And do not hardcode the file path like that, the application is never going to work when deployed in Mule. Instead, put `usermap.xml` in `src/main/resources` and load it as a classpath resource with `Thread.currentThread().getContextClassloader().getResourceAsStream("usermap.xml")`

PS. What' with all the static variables at the top? If they're constant, make them final as well. And name them `THE_JAVA_WAY` for constants.